# using awk to selectively change word order in a column

Tags: awk

I want to change this text:

```
Fred Flintstone:father:male
Wilma Flintstone:mother:female
Flintstone, Pebbles:daughter:female
Barney Rubble:father:male
Rubble, Betty:mother:female
Bam Bam Rubble:son:male
```

into:

```
Flintstone, Fred:father:male
Flintstone, Wilma:mother:female
Flintstone, Pebbles:daughter:female
Rubble, Barney:father:male
Rubble, Betty:mother:female
Rubble, Bam Bam:son:male
```

Is it possible to do this in one line of awk? Or is it better to extract the first column manipulate the text and reimport the column?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible in one line of awk :) have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gawk one liner:

```
awk -F: '$1=gensub(/([^,]+)[ ]+([^ ,]+)/,"\\2, \\1","1",$1)' yourfile
```

- it uses `:` a delimiter with the `-F` option
- the `gensub` function is used on `$1` in the pattern part:

  - if a replacement was possible, the expression is true and modifies `$1`

    - the default action print is used implicitly.
  - if the expression does not match (due to a comma in `$1`) the line is implicitly printed

Answer (score 0):

*Any* awk program can be one line.  Doing it without semicolons is harder.

I came up with the following:

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }

$1 !~ /,/ {
    match( $1, / [^ ]+$/ )
    n = RSTART
    name = substr($1, n+1) ", " substr($1, 1, n-1)
    gsub( /^[^:]+/, name)
    print
    next
}

{ print }
```

I think that's standard awk.  It doesn't rely on back-references, nor on match() returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
{
    rest = last = $1
    sub(/.*[ ,]/,"",last)
    sub(/[ ,]+[^ ]+$/,"",rest)
    $1 = last ", " rest
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Flintstone, Fred:father:male
Flintstone, Wilma:mother:female
Pebbles, Flintstone:daughter:female
Rubble, Barney:father:male
Betty, Rubble:mother:female
Rubble, Bam Bam:son:male
```